# How does Ruby determine how many buckets are in a hash?

Tags: ruby

I was learning about hash buckets from a Udacity course and I was wondering how many hash buckets are created when a hash is created in Ruby. I'm less interested in the hashing function, the one that distributes values across the buckets and does the lookup in constant time. I'm more concerned with the number of buckets and the number of objects in each bucket.

**My main questions:**
1. Generally speaking, what kind of algorithm does Ruby use to determine how many buckets are created and how many key-value lists are stored in each bucket? How does Ruby do this behind the scenes?
2. Is the hash/dictionary in Ruby a hash-bucket-like hash?

Comment: https://launchschool.com/blog/how-the-hash-works-in-ruby

Comment: Short answer: Magic. Long answer: Read the source code. Each implementation may vary considerably (e.g. Ruby 1.8, 2.0, 2.3, JRuby, etc.)

Answer (score -3):

Ruby does nothing of the sort. The Ruby Language Specification does not specify any particular implementation strategy for the `Hash` class, it only specifies its semantics. In fact, the ISO Ruby Language Specification doesn't even guarantee O(1) access.

Every Ruby implementation implements `Hash` differently. In IronRuby, `RubyHash` simply inherits from .NET's `Dictionary<object, object>`. Rubinius recently switched to a HAMT (Hash Array Mapped Trie) which means it doesn't even use a hash table anymore.

If you want to know how some particular Ruby implementation implements the `Hash` class, you will have to look at the source code for that particular Ruby implementation.

Comment: What are some common implementations of ruby?

Comment: Some I know of are Topaz, MagLev, Rubinius, IronRuby (actually, there also was a second, unrelated implementation with that same name), JRuby, Cardinal, Opal, MacRuby, Ruby.NET, XRuby, RubyMotion, tinyrb, RubyGoLightly, BlueRuby, SmallRuby, Alumina, Corundum, Smalltalk.rb, YARI/IoRuby, MRuby, YARV, MRI. Those are just the ones that spring to mind, I believe there are more.

Comment: What's the ruby I get from RVM and rubygems?

Comment: RubyGems is a Ruby library. RVM lets you install many different implementations of Ruby; you get the one you tell it to install.